# No puedo configurar flask en modo debug

Tags: python, flask

Estoy realizando mi primer proyecto con flask, y se me ha presentado un problema con la configuración del servidor para que esté en modo debug.
intento con `set FLASK_DEBUG=1` y con  `set FLASK_ENV=development`   y nada.

Comparto el proyecto en git:
https://github.com/elkinddv/EvaluApp/tree/master/app

Agradezco quien me pueda ayudar y explique la razón por la cual no funciona.

Agrego imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No deberías usar `flask --app example --debug `?

Comment: No funciona con la forma que está estructurado el proyecto, que inicia desde el archivo `__init__.py`

Comment: Revice el repositorio de tu proyecto y ejecute el comando que comenta Mauicio `flask --app app --debug run ` y muetra el siguiente mensaje  `* Debugger is active!`.  Como estas ejecutando flask desde la consola?

Comment: intenta agregando `app.debug = True` en la configuración de tu `app`

Comment: @Sr1871 no funciona tampoco.

Comment: @GmrYael estoy ejecuntando flask desde la terminal de VSC

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda que coloques una imagen de cómo lo estás haciendo  y ver la salida de consola, porque personalmente probé tu código y funciona con lo que comento @MauricioContreras

Comment: @GmrYael Agregue la imagen, ...y entonces no sé por qué no funciona en mi terminal

Comment: Me refería la imagen donde ejecutas el comando que te recomendó Mauricio y ver la salida de la consola.

Comment: Saludos, gracias a todos por sus respuestas, les cuento que por fin pude solucionar desde la terminal, con los comandos

`$env:FLASK_APP="app"`
`$env:FLASK_ENV="development"`

con `set` aparentemente no funciona desde la terminal